# Query runs much slower using JDBC

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

### I have two different queries that take about the same amount of time to execute when I timed with Adminer or DBeaver

**Query one**

```
select * from state where state_name = 'Florida';
```

When I run the query above in Adminer it takes anywhere from

> 0.032 s to 0.058 s

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..3981.50 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=1.787..15.047 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (state_name = 'Florida'::citext)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 50
Planning Time: 0.486 ms
Execution Time: 15.779 ms
```

**Query two**

```
select
    property.id as property_id ,
    full_address,
    street_address,
    street.street,
    city.city as city,
    state.state_code as state_code,
    zipcode.zipcode as zipcode
from
    property
inner join street on
    street.id = property.street_id
inner join city on
    city.id = property.city_id
inner join state on
    state.id = property.state_id
inner join zipcode on
    zipcode.id = property.zipcode_id
where
    full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211';
```

The above query takes from

> 0.025 s to 0.048 s

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Nested Loop  (cost=29.82..65.96 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.668..0.671 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.53..57.65 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=0.617..0.620 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.25..49.30 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=0.582..0.585 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28.97..41.00 rows=1 width=127) (actual time=0.532..0.534 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on property  (cost=28.54..32.56 rows=1 width=131) (actual time=0.454..0.456 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::citext)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=1
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on property_full_address  (cost=0.00..28.54 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.426..0.426 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::citext)
                    ->  Index Scan using street_pkey on street  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.070..0.070 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id = property.street_id)
              ->  Index Scan using city_id_pk on city  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.047..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = property.city_id)
        ->  Index Scan using state_id_pk on state  (cost=0.28..8.32 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = property.state_id)
  ->  Index Scan using zipcode_id_pk on zipcode  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = property.zipcode_id)
Planning Time: 5.473 ms
Execution Time: 1.601 ms
```

### I have the following methods which uses JDBCTemplate to execute the same queries.

**Query one**

```
public void performanceTest(String str) {
    template.queryForObject(
            "select * from state where state_name = ?",
            new Object[] { str }, (result, rowNum) -> {
                return result.getObject("state_name");
            });

}
```

> time: 140ms, which is 0.14 seconds

**Query two**

```
public void performanceTest(String str) {
    template.queryForObject(
            "SELECT property.id AS property_id , full_address, street_address, street.street, city.city as city, state.state_code as state_code, zipcode.zipcode as zipcode FROM property INNER JOIN street ON street.id = property.street_id INNER JOIN city ON city.id = property.city_id INNER JOIN state ON state.id = property.state_id INNER JOIN zipcode ON zipcode.id = property.zipcode_id WHERE full_address = ?",
            new Object[] { str }, (result, rowNum) -> {
                return result.getObject("property_id");
            });

}
```

The time it takes to execute the method above is

> time: 828 ms, which is 0.825 seconds

I am timing the method's execution time using this code below

```
long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
propertyRepo.performanceTest(address); //or "Florida" depending which query I'm testing
long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
long duration1 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert((endTime1 - startTime1), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
System.out.println("time: " + duration1);
```

Why is query two so much slower when I run it from JDBC compared to when I run it from Adminer? Anything I can do to improve the performance for query two?

**EDIT:**

I created two different PHP scripts containing the queries respectively. They take the same amount of time using PHP, so I assume it has something to do with JDBC? Below is the result of the PHP scripts. The time PHP takes is a higher than Java takes with Query one since I am not using any connection pooling. But both queries are taking pretty much the same amount of time to execute. Something is causing a delay with Query two on JDBC.

[image]

**EDIT:**

When I run the query using prepared statement it's slow. But it's fast when I run it with statement. I did EXPLAIN ANALYZE for both, using preparedStatement and statement

**preparedStatement explain analyze**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1.27..315241.91 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.091..688.583 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..315233.61 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=0.079..688.571 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..315225.26 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=0.069..688.561 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..315216.95 rows=1 width=127) (actual time=0.057..688.548 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on property  (cost=0.00..315208.51 rows=1 width=131) (actual time=0.032..688.522 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((full_address)::text = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 8790
                    ->  Index Scan using street_pkey on street  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id = property.street_id)
              ->  Index Scan using city_id_pk on city  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = property.city_id)
        ->  Index Scan using state_id_pk on state  (cost=0.28..8.32 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = property.state_id)
  ->  Index Scan using zipcode_id_pk on zipcode  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = property.zipcode_id)
Planning Time: 2.400 ms
Execution Time: 688.674 ms
```

**statement explain analyze**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=29.82..65.96 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.232..0.235 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.53..57.65 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=0.220..0.223 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.25..49.30 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=0.211..0.213 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28.97..41.00 rows=1 width=127) (actual time=0.198..0.200 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on property  (cost=28.54..32.56 rows=1 width=131) (actual time=0.175..0.177 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::citext)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=1
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on property_full_address  (cost=0.00..28.54 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.162..0.162 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::citext)
                    ->  Index Scan using street_pkey on street  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id = property.street_id)
              ->  Index Scan using city_id_pk on city  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = property.city_id)
        ->  Index Scan using state_id_pk on state  (cost=0.28..8.32 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = property.state_id)
  ->  Index Scan using zipcode_id_pk on zipcode  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = property.zipcode_id)
Planning Time: 2.442 ms
Execution Time: 0.345 ms
```

Comment: how much data is involved in query , try creating database index on full_address and state_name

Comment: Wouldn’t you mind to post the database system you use?  Most probably in the first query you observe the JDBC Template overhead. The second query could trigger a different execution plan due to use of the bind variable - but this is all speculation if you keep your RDBMS secret;)

Comment: The indexes are already there. The query runs fast outside of my Java application. And Query two runs faster than query one when ran in Adminer. I don't understand why query two runs slower than query one in my Java application

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I use Postgresql. I can post the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` if it helps.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I have attached the EXPLAIN ANALYZE for each query

Comment: @david now check the execution plan for the secodn query if you use a *bind variable* for the `full_address` (and not a literal string). I suspect you will see a different plan.  Alternatively you may test the literal string usage in JDBCTemplate query.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber isn't binding variable when running a query from inside a programming language?

Comment: can you try executing the query with plain JDBC program just to find the difference

Comment: @ShaileshChandra I tried it with JDBC, with preparedStatement it's also slow. But with statement it's much much faster. About 8X times faster

Comment: at least problem is isolated now, its nothing related to spring,  just a random thought, are you using the latest JDBC driver for your database

Comment: The issue was found. This is the question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739859/query-much-slower-with-preparedstatement-compared-to-statement/58740057#58740057

Answer (score -2):

It's because of the connection pool that is used by the different clients.
You can setup a fast connection pool like HikariC for JDBC like this:

```
public class HikariCPDataSource {

    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource ds;

    static {
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        config.setUsername("user");
        config.setPassword("password");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

    private HikariCPDataSource(){}
}
```

Comment: As far I know JDBCTempalate, is already using connection pooling with Hikari

Comment: @david Spring Boot will try to load available [connection pool](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql) for your DataSource:

_We prefer HikariCP for its performance and concurrency. If HikariCP is available, we always choose it. Otherwise, if the Tomcat pooling DataSource is available, we use it. Else if Commons DBCP2 is available, we use it. If you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa “starters”, you automatically get a dependency to HikariCP._

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.0 and do have the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` in my pom.xml I think everything is automatically configured?

Comment: The connection pool has no influence on the actual execution of a query. The "performance" of a pool refers to it's ability to work under high load where a lot of connections are taken out from the pool from many concurrent threads. But once the statement execution starts, the pool is completely irrelevant