# query much slower with preparedStatement compared to statement

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have two different methods that contain the same SQL query. The fist one uses preparedStatement which is very slow

```
public String getPropertyPreparedStatement(String address) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String content = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(template.getDataSource());

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(
                "EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT property.id AS property_id , full_address, street_address, street.street, city.city as city, state.state_code as state_code, zipcode.zipcode as zipcode FROM property INNER JOIN street ON street.id = property.street_id INNER JOIN city ON city.id = property.city_id INNER JOIN state ON state.id = property.state_id INNER JOIN zipcode ON zipcode.id = property.zipcode_id WHERE full_address = ?");
        pst.setString(1, address);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            // content = rs.getString("street_address");
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (pst != null) {
            pst.close();
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the method above is below

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1.27..315241.91 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.091..688.583 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..315233.61 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=0.079..688.571 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..315225.26 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=0.069..688.561 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..315216.95 rows=1 width=127) (actual time=0.057..688.548 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on property  (cost=0.00..315208.51 rows=1 width=131) (actual time=0.032..688.522 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((full_address)::text = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 8790
                    ->  Index Scan using street_pkey on street  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id = property.street_id)
              ->  Index Scan using city_id_pk on city  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = property.city_id)
        ->  Index Scan using state_id_pk on state  (cost=0.28..8.32 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = property.state_id)
  ->  Index Scan using zipcode_id_pk on zipcode  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = property.zipcode_id)
Planning Time: 2.400 ms
Execution Time: 688.674 ms
```

The method below uses statement and I have the address directly in the query to test performance

```
public String getPropertyStatement() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String content = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(template.getDataSource());
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                "EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT property.id AS property_id , full_address, street_address, street.street, city.city as city, state.state_code as state_code, zipcode.zipcode as zipcode FROM property INNER JOIN street ON street.id = property.street_id INNER JOIN city ON city.id = property.city_id INNER JOIN state ON state.id = property.state_id INNER JOIN zipcode ON zipcode.id = property.zipcode_id WHERE full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'");

        while (rs.next()) {
            // content = rs.getString("street_address");
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the method above

```
Nested Loop  (cost=29.82..65.96 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.232..0.235 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.53..57.65 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=0.220..0.223 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.25..49.30 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=0.211..0.213 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28.97..41.00 rows=1 width=127) (actual time=0.198..0.200 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on property  (cost=28.54..32.56 rows=1 width=131) (actual time=0.175..0.177 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::citext)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=1
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on property_full_address  (cost=0.00..28.54 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.162..0.162 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (full_address = '139-Skillman-Ave-Apt-5C-Brooklyn-NY-11211'::citext)
                    ->  Index Scan using street_pkey on street  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id = property.street_id)
              ->  Index Scan using city_id_pk on city  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id = property.city_id)
        ->  Index Scan using state_id_pk on state  (cost=0.28..8.32 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = property.state_id)
  ->  Index Scan using zipcode_id_pk on zipcode  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = property.zipcode_id)
Planning Time: 2.442 ms
Execution Time: 0.345 ms
```

When I run the query on the database directly it's also very fast, pretty much like the method that uses statement instead of preparedStatement.

Why is the preparedStatement so much slower? What options do I have to keep the performance of using statement while still being able to use a placeholder in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prepared statement casts `full_address` into `text` (Postgres' built-in text type), whereas it seems that your table is created with a `citext` (case-insensitive) text type (or, you lack an index on `full_address::text`).  Maybe try creating an index on `full_address::text` and see if your prepared statement will pick it up.

Another option is to use a `text` type for the `full_address` column, and then create a functional index on `lower(full_address)` -- the palatability of that option depends on what your requirements are.

I think that part of the problem is that JDBC doesn't know about the `citext` type so unless you can get JDBC to send your address to the database as a `citext` type, it's going to be interpreted by the query planner as `text`, just as your `setString()` method probably does.

Interestingly, I [ran into a similar issue recently](http://richyen.com/postgres/2019/11/06/auto_explain.html)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: you are right that was the issue, the way I fixed it by casting it to `citext` example: `WHERE full_address = ?::citext`